# mcv application where to adapt model data for the view?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I'm implementing a fairly simple application in javascript using the MVC approach. My views are using mustache as templating system.
When the application loads an api gets queried and it returns a complex object which I store in the model. When it's time to visualise the data on the view I'd need to transform this complex object in a much simpler version with less properties and nesting, in order for the template engine to be able to display the view.

I'm wondering if it's controller responsability to "adapt" the data for the view or this process should be delegated to some other  part of the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should create DTO object and map that object to you ViewModel

Answer (score 1):

I use [Automapper](http://automapper.org/) to do convert entity framework models to simpler Viewmodels/DTO objects. It works by convention and when the convention doesn't work, you use a fluent API to tell it how to convert the properties.

Very simple to use and you only need to define your mapping logic once, which is exactly what you want.